# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' in cursor

Tags: python-2.7

I researched posts with the same error result but think mine is happening when my cursor runs into a null value in my table and tries to perform a split. I tried using a conditional statement for the program to continue running if it ran into a None value but still getting the same error. Here's my code:

```
f1 = "Address"

f2 = "Cust1stStWord"

f3 = "ST_NM_BASE"

f4 = "Street1stStWord"

print "Running cursors"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("gimLyrJoin",[f1, f2, f3, f4]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[2] != None:
            continue
        # first update fields with street names that have directional prefixes
        if len(row[0].split(" ")[1]) == 1 and row[0].split(" ")[2] != "ST":
            row[1] = row[0].split(" ")[2][0:3]
            row[3] = row[2].split(" ")[2][0:3]
        # now look for street names that start with SAINT in customer records and change them to ST
        elif row[0].split(" ")[1] == "SAINT":
            row[1] = "ST "
            row[3] = row[2].split(" ")[1][0:3]
        #Change remaining records to first three letters of street name
        else:
            row[1] = row[0].split(" ")[1][0:3]
            row[3] = row[2].split(" ")[1][0:3]
        cursor.UpdateRow(row)
```

And here is the error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\Python\Completed scripts\GIM_Street_Updates.py", line 78, in <module>
    row[3] = row[2].split(" ")[1][0:3]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Which line with split() gives an error?

Comment: Not positive but pretty sure the first line with split on it. Will provide full traceback in post.

Comment: Here is no information where is an error. Try to add debug messages before every line with split().

Comment: It's in the else statement. Added debugger line to error section of post.

Comment: Print row[2] before the line with error.

Comment: You *do* know that calling `split()` without arguments will split on whitespace, right?

Comment: @Michael O running now

Comment: @MattDMo So does that mean null values are not causing the error and the continue statement is unnecessary?

Comment: @Michael O. print statement returned None

Comment: @ShaunO So, you have to do smth with row[2] or handle a situation when it is None.

Comment: @ Michael O. I thought that's what I was doing with the continue statement at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: @ShaunO You're doing the opposite, going to start of loop when row[2] isn't None.

Comment: Thank you for the push Michael O and MattDMo

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the loop I made a condition to find where row[2] == None an changed the value to " " and entered an Updaterow(row) and continue statement at the end of the condition so the split method would not throw the error later in the loop:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("gimLyrJoin",[f1, f2, f3, f4]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            # fix null values
            if row[2] == None:
                row[2] = " "
                cursor.updateRow(row)
                continue
            elif len(row[0].split(" ")[1]) == 1 and row[0].split(" ")[2] != "ST":
                row[1] = row[0].split(" ")[2][0:3]
                # ST_NM_BASE seems to not include prefix so okay to 0 index
                row[3] = row[2].split(" ")[0][0:3]
            # now look for street names that start with SAINT in customer records and change them to ST
            elif row[0].split(" ")[1] == "SAINT":
                row[1] = "ST "
                row[3] = row[2].split(" ")[0][0:3]
            #Change remaining records to first three letters of street name
            else:
                row[1] = row[0].split(" ")[1][0:3]
                row[3] = row[2].split(" ")[0][0:3]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```